# Как получить подмассив массива на Java?

Tags: java, массивы

К примеру, есть массив из 55 элементов:

```
int[] mas = new int[55];
```

Нужно из него сделать новый массив:

```
mas = new int[40]
```

где 40 элементов итоговые это первые 40 элементов из первоначального массива в 55 элеметов, первые 40 нужно оставить, последние 15 - выкинуть.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В Java есть стандартная функция для вырезания части массива

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, startIndex, endIndex);
```

Т.е. в вашем случае

```
newMas = Arrays.copyOfRange(mas, 0, 40);
```

Обратите внимание, что элемент с индексом `endIndex` не будет включен. То есть этой командой будут извлечены элементы с индексами `0..39`

Comment: большое спасибо :)